# Avoiding Numba CUDA Jit Race Condition

Tags: python, numpy, cuda, numba

I have a simple example:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import math

@cuda.jit
def func(i, y, z):
    start = cuda.grid(1)
    stride = cuda.gridsize(1)

    for j in range(start, y.shape[0], stride):
        # Note that these aren't my real functions but they demo the point
        if i < j:
            y[j, 0] = i
            z[j, 0] = i + j
        if i == j:
            y[j, 1] = i
            z[j, 1] = i * j
        if i > j:
            y[j, 2] = i
            z[j, 2] = j


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 30
    y = np.ones((n, 3))
    z = np.ones((n, 3)) * -1
    device_y = cuda.to_device(y)
    device_z = cuda.to_device(z)
    max_i = 5
    threads_per_block = 10
    blocks_per_grid = math.ceil(y.shape[0]/threads_per_block[1])

    for i in range(max_i):
        func[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](i, device_y, device_z)

    out = device_y.copy_to_host()
    print(out)
```

And the output should look like this:

```
[[1. 0. 4.]
 [0. 1. 4.]
 [1. 2. 4.]
 [2. 3. 4.]
 [3. 4. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]]
```

However, when `max_i` is large then most of the time is spend calling the CUDA kernel and I want to make this kernel as fast as possible. So, I'm trying to figure out how to move the `max_i` for loop into the kernel but it looks like I am getting into race conditions. Here's what I currently have:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import math

@cuda.jit
def func(max_i, y, z):
    a, b = cuda.grid(2)
    a_stride, b_stride = cuda.gridsize(2)

    for i in range(a, max_i, a_stride):
        for j in range(b, y.shape[0], b_stride):
            if i < j:
                y[j, 0] = i
                z[j, 0] = i + j
            if i == j:
                y[j, 1] = i
                z[j, 1] = i * j
            if i > j:
                y[j, 2] = i
                z[j, 2] = j

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 30
    y = np.ones((n, 3))
    z = np.ones((n, 3)) * -1
    device_y = cuda.to_device(y)
    device_z = cuda.to_device(z)
    max_i = 5
    threads_per_block = (1, 10)
    blocks_per_grid = (max_i, math.ceil(y.shape[0]/threads_per_block[1]))

    func[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](max_i, device_y, device_z)

    out = device_y.copy_to_host()
    print(out)
```

And this (incorrect) output looks like:

```
[[1. 0. 4.]
 [0. 1. 4.]
 [1. 2. 4.]
 [1. 3. 4.]  # Should be [2. 3. 4.]
 [3. 4. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [3. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [3. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [3. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [3. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1.]]  # Should be [4. 1. 1.]
```

As stated above, how do I obtain the right answer by using a single kernel while making this kernel as fast as possible (i.e., avoiding atomic operations)?

Comment: going from your first example to the second, presumably you were demonstrating bringing 5 of the `max_i` loops into the kernel, you made two changes: 1. You increased the grid by 5x, 2.  you added a loop inside the kernel.  Conceptually, you only needed one of those changes.  But the bigger issue here is that keeping that loop out of the kernel meant you had a grid-wide sync at each kernel call, which I think is necessary for your algorithm.  The loop inside the kernel doesn't obviate the need for that.  Atomics won't fix that.  You need an in-kernel grid sync, and numba cuda doesn't have that

Comment: Yes, your observations are correct. I added a second dimension thinking that I can enforce, say, `i=2` be executed only after all of `i=1` are started (or at the same time). Then, I’d have `i=1` results (and all `i=odd`) write to a separate `y_odd` and `z_odd` while `i=2` (and all `i=even`) will write to a `y_even` and `z_even`. But I realize that this is an issue if the total number of threads is greater than `2 * x.shape[0]` since there will be enough threads for `i=3` to execute at the same time as `i=1` and now I have the same race condition but for odds and evens. What are my options?

Comment: The sensible option in my opinion was the code realization you had in your previous question.  I didn't bother working on that question because you didn't provide a test case, and no I'm not going to try to reverse engineer a kernel to figure out how to wrap it with enough code to make a test case.  You presumably already have that and decided not to provide it.  So I decided not to pay attention.  A performance question without a test case IMO is "unclear and not useful".

Comment: If you really, really want to push a grid sync into the kernel, the right way to do it is not exposed in any cuda python implementation I am aware of (yet).  You could build your kernel into a library in CUDA C++ and call it from python using python ctypes.  Probably there are other approaches.  But I wouldn't do all that work without understanding the scope of the problem and probably some profiling.  Can't do that with just a kernel.

Comment: So, considering that having the `i` for loop outside of the kernel produces the right answer but it causes many slow/costly kernel calls, is there a better way to call the kernel many times from the Python `i` for loop? The point of trying to push the for loop into the kernel was to speed things up and I feel like I an so close yet so far away.

Comment: As for my previous question, you are absolutely right and I can only ask for your patience and forgiveness. This CUDA stuff is completely new to me and so I am operating at the edge of my limited understanding. So it is hard to even figure out exactly what I should be asking. Hopefully, this question is better. I found that the contents of the kernel didn’t matter (I was able to comment out the body of the kernel and got the same timing results with large `max_i`) as 98-99% of the time was actually being spent calling the kernel. Thank you for taking the time to help me with this question!

Answer (score 3):

> As stated above, how do I obtain the right answer by using a single kernel while making this kernel as fast as possible (i.e., avoiding atomic operations)?

For the size of data you have shown here, a trivially simple approach would be just to do everything in one CUDA threadblock, place a block synchronization at the end of the loop and place the `max_i` loop directly into the kernel:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import math

@cuda.jit
def func(max_i, y, z):
    start = cuda.grid(1)
    stride = cuda.gridsize(1)
    for i in range(max_i):
        for j in range(start, y.shape[0], stride):
            if i < j:
                y[j, 0] = i
                z[j, 0] = i + j
            if i == j:
                y[j, 1] = i
                z[j, 1] = i * j
            if i > j:
                y[j, 2] = i
                z[j, 2] = j
        cuda.syncthreads()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 30
    y = np.ones((n, 3))
    z = np.ones((n, 3)) * -1
    device_y = cuda.to_device(y)
    device_z = cuda.to_device(z)
    max_i = 5
    threads_per_block = 1024
    blocks_per_grid = 1

    func[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](max_i, device_y, device_z)

    out = device_y.copy_to_host()
    print(out)
```

This will work for `n` values up to 1024.  However in the general case, where `n` is larger than 1024, we need a different approach.  To extend the previous approach, we would need a grid-wide sync (when we go beyond a single block) but I'm not aware of any CUDA python implementations that provide this, although [CUDA C++ does](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/).
Running CUDA codes that consist of a single block is usually not a very good way to tap into GPU performance anyway.

Instead, we can make the observation for the functions you have shown, that only one value ends up in each location in the output array, even though each location may have been written more than once.  So our challenge becomes to determine what is the correct output value (i.e. what would have been the final value written to that location, given the number of `max_i` loops), with a single pass over each location.  Here's a worked example generating just the `y` output:

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np
import math

@cuda.jit
def func(max_i, y, z):
    start = cuda.grid(1)
    stride = cuda.gridsize(1)
    for j in range(start, y.shape[0], stride):
        if j > 0:
            y[j, 0] = min(max_i-1, j-1)
#            z[j, 0] = i+j
        if j < max_i:
            y[j, 1] = j
#            z[j, 1] = i * j
        if j < max_i-1:
            y[j, 2] = max_i-1
#            z[j, 2] = j

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = 30
    y = np.ones((n, 3))
    z = np.ones((n, 3)) * -1
    device_y = cuda.to_device(y)
    device_z = cuda.to_device(z)
    max_i = 5
    threads_per_block = 1024
    blocks_per_grid = 1

    func[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](max_i, device_y, device_z)

    out = device_y.copy_to_host()
    print(out)
```

It should be possible with a similar methodology to generate the `z` values.  This method should work for `n` values greater than 1024 (using suitable block and grid sizing arithmetic, not depicted here, but following generally what you have in your examples).